# JAVA - RadioButton checked

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have one problem with my application. I have two `RadioButton` :

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
<!-- android:buttonTint="@color/BouttonsRadio" --> 

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Boutton_Bluetooth"
        android:id="@+id/BouttonRADIO_Bluetooth"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Boutton_RS232"
        android:id="@+id/BouttonRADIO_RS232"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RadioGroup>
```

And, I have one `AlertDialog`, who have three buttons :

```
    public void fenetre_connexiondeconnexion() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);


    final View view2 = View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.fenetre_connexion_B_R, null);


    // Titre de la fenêtre
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Paramètres connexion");
    alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.logo_connecterdeconnecter);

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Veuillez choisir le type de connexion :")
            .setCancelable(false);

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(view2);


    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("CONNEXION", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // if this button is clicked, close
            // current activity
            connexion_rs232();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("ANNULER", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // if this button is clicked, just close
            // the dialog box and do nothing
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    })
            .setNeutralButton("PARAMETRES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    fenetre_parametres_rs232(view2);
                }
            });




    // Création de la fenêtre
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();


    // Affichage de la fenêtre
    alertDialog.show();


}
```

Finally, and I will want to retrieve the radio button checked, and ONLY if it's the Bluetooth, disable the neutral `Button`.
For this, I have found this, but didn't work :

```
Button button = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);

if(BouttonRadio_B.isChecked()) {
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
if(BouttonRadio_R.isChecked()) {
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: In which  class and method do you have the code you provided in the last for obtaining the button of the dialog and checking if radio button (either of the two) is checked and then enabling/disabling the button of the remote

Comment: @nits.kk : My class is MainActivity.java, and my method is in Mainactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the listener to listen the check change listener of `RadioButton`. See [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) for more details.And yes you can use `button.setEnabled(isChecked)`:

```
BouttonRadio_R.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
    {
       if (isChecked) {
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }
       else{
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }
}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Would you indicate in your answer why this is a good solution to the problem presented? Also, could you just do `button.setEnabled(isChecked)`? - that would save an if/else structure.

Comment: You have to implement the listener to listen the check change listener of RadioButton.See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) for more details.And yes you can use **button.setEnabled(isChecked)**.Please upvote if it helped.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited it in for you, please be willing to do that yourself in future. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

It's must work

```
    Button button = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
    if(BouttonRadio_B.isChecked()) {
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
    if(BouttonRadio_R.isChecked()) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

If this code will be executed after showing the dialogue

```
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Krumish : I'm OK with your code. I add this code, after my alerttdialog.show(). The app compile without error, but when I click on the item, on my menu, who use this method, the app FC.